# How do I make my wordpress page more friendly for mobile viewers?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, javascript, html

My basic question is **How do I make my wordpress page more friendly for mobile viewers?**

I have seen some answers such as [wptouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/), [wordpress mobile pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/), and mobilepress http ://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobilepress/ .

All great, however I enjoy my theme and was wondering if there is a way to not-autoload images, and if there are some more versatile themes which can scale to smaller screens.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably refer to [Responsive themes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design) that are appropriate for both desktops, tablets, mobile phones. This requires some CSS and markup alterations (actually a bit of work and testing) so that a theme looks good in any device including portrait or landscape view in mobile devices.

Unless you want to use a mobile plugin, there are lots of premium themes in markets such as ThemeForest or the [Responsive](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/responsive) free theme from WPORG repo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for the most part it is all theme related. The best one I've used is Weaver II which you can try out for free here: http://weavertheme.com/ comes with a mobile version with the theme download I believe. There is a Pro version as well that you can check out here: http://pro.weavertheme.com/

Answer (score 0):

As far as the not autoloading images goes, there was some discussion on this topic over at http://reddit.com/r/wordpress a few weeks ago.

Check out the post here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/ucy8k/responsive_images_for_wordpress_opinions_ides/